# How can I arrange duplicate numbers together (preferably in an array) and separate them based on which number it is?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a game where I want to simulate poker style hands. The hand is an array of 5 values right now. The values are randomly generated. For example, I might have hand = [1, 1, 2, 4, 4] or I might have hand = [1, 2, 2, 2, 6].

I want to be able to take duplicate numbers in the hand array and return a value based on how many duplicates there are, and how many groups of duplicates there are. In the 1st example, 1, 1 is the 1st group. 4, 4 is the 2nd group. Therefore, there are 2 groups of 2. In the 2nd example, 2, 2, 2 is one group of 3.

From there, I can create a simple set of return statements. So, the 1st example would return "Two Pairs". The 2nd example would return "Three of a Kind".

I've tried various forEach loops with conditions.

For example,

```
handCombo() {
        let group1 = [], group2 = [];

        this.hand.forEach((card, index) => {
            //  1. If the index is 0, push the value to the group1
            if (index === 0) {
                group1.push(card.value);
            }
            else if (index > 0 && group1[index - 1] === card) {
                group1.push(card.value);
            }
            else if (index > 0 && group1[index - 1] === card) {
                group1.push(card.value);
            }

        });
```

When the hand = [1, 2, 2, 2, 6], this produces an array, group1 = [1]. What I want is group1 = [2, 2, 2] in that case.

Comment: please add your tries and the wanted result if it differs from the given data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the same values and return a customized result.

```js
function x(hand) {
    var count = {},
        pairs = 0,
        three = 0,
        s = '';
        
    hand.forEach(v => count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1);
    Object.values(count).forEach(c => {
        if (c === 3) three++;
        if (c === 2) pairs++;    
    });
    if (three) s = 'Three of a Kind';
    if (pairs === 1) s += (s && ' and ') + 'One Pair';
    if (pairs === 2) s = 'Two Pairs';
    return s;
}

console.log([[1, 1, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 2, 6], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].map(x)); // "Two Pairs" "Three of a Kind".
```

Comment: Can you explain how this condition `(s && ' and ')` works?

Comment: it takes the second `' and '` if `s` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) like a nonempty string. if `s` is an empty string, then the empty string is added.

Answer (score 0):

This code will answer your question. This code for number of duplicate.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 6];
let groups = {};
for(let num of arr) {
  let numStr = num.toString();
  if (!groups[numStr]) groups[numStr] = 0;
  groups[numStr]++;
}

console.log(groups);

for(let no in groups) {
    console.log("no", no, "have ", groups[no]);
}
```

If what you want is array in group. use this code.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 6];
let groups = {};
for (let num of arr) {
    let numStr = num.toString();
    if (!groups[numStr]) groups[numStr] = [];
    groups[numStr].push(num);
}

console.log(groups);

for (let no in groups) {
    console.log("no", no, "have ", groups[no]);
}
```